# Ruby on rails get and save values on array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm working with a Weather API and that's give the rainProb field with 4 values  with 8 hours difference and i want to assign this value to every hour.

In other words that is:

```
10 => 02
10 => 03
10 => 04
10 => 05
10 => 06
10 => 07
10 => 08
0  => 09
```

...
So thats the code:

```
 "probPrecipitacion"=>

  [{"value"=>"10", "periodo"=>"0208"},

   {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"0814"},

   {"value"=>"5", "periodo"=>"1420"},

   {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"2002"}],
```

This are the meanings of the "periodo"

```
0208 = 02:00 to 08:00

0814 = 08:00 to 14:00

1420 = 14:00 to 20:00

2002 = 20:00 to 20:00
```

And to get the code from de json i do this:

```
arr_rain_prob = json.dig(0,'prediccion','dia',1,'probPrecipitacion').map{ |e| e['value']}
arr_periodo_prob = json.dig(0,'prediccion','dia',1,'probPrecipitacion').map{ |e| e['periodo']}  

hourly_forecast.rain = arr_rain_prob[hour] #hour is and iterative that goes to 0 to 23
```

arr_rain_prob contains this values = 10 0 5 0
arr_periodo_prob contains this values = 0208 0814 1420 2002

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand the question; what is the desired outcome/result? What is `hourly_forecast`? What is `hourly_forecast.rain`? Are you asking how to convert that data into a `Hash` like: `{2 => 10, 3 => 10, 4=> 10, ..., 8 => 0, 9 => 0, ...}`, or are you asking for wider advice on how to store the data, considering it spans multiple days (and a single set of data awkwardly goes across midnight!!)

Comment: There also seems to be some confusion about the **boundaries** of the data: You are mapping `2 => 10`, but also `8 => 10` (not `8 => 0`)??

Comment: The objective of the code is store the data in the model (HourlyForecast).
hourly_forecast.rain is a field of the model.
I don't want to convert data into Hash, i want to operate with the hash to get the hours between all the values

Comment: What do you want hourly_forecast.rain to equal?

Comment: I want to store all the values in hourly_forecast.rain

Comment: OK, and what do you want it to equal? If you inspect `hourly_forecast.rain`, what value do you want this to show?